# Using SplashScreenService to build up application

Tags: c#, mvvm, catel

I am trying to use the SplashScreenService to show the user the progress of starting the application. Within the tasks I am creating the logger, the container, configuring the container, creating and initializing my MainWindow (View+ViewModel) and so on ... the tasks of a bootstrapper.

But the SplashScreenService refuses his work when committing because of `Application.Current.MainWindow == null`. The thing is that `Application.Current.MainWindow` is set within the initalization task.
I could workaround this with temporaly setting `Application.Current.MainWindow = new Window()` before the `splashScreenService.Commit()` and fixing the issue with [MainWindow gets closed after SplashScreen is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659965/splashscreenservice-doesnt-work-as-i-want#comment29264749_19660596) by setting the owner to null of my MainWindow (the owner was set to the PleaseWait dialog which therefor also closes the MainWindow).

So why must the `Application.Current.MainWindow` be set to get the SplashScreenService working? Within the service there is no code that uses this property. And I can only create my MainWindow after all other tasks are completed - a real chicken-and-egg problem!

Comment: Just checked the source code, I see it's a bit misleading. Can you try CommitAsync instead to see if that works?

Comment: I did. But it's an endless loop as long as the MainWindow is not set ;-)
Info: I am still on Catel 4.1.0 ... going on to 4.2.0 next week.

Comment: Let me know how 4.2 behaves. If still buggy, create a ticket please.

Comment: Still behaves the same ... creating ticket.

Comment: See https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-733.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it when I have time.